# Searching for selecting data and printing it in a specific manar

Tags: visual-c++

I want to read a file that has text and numbers in it but I don't want it to be displayed as it's stored on the file like:

getline(file, line);
cout << line;

Rather I want to display in a specific manner like taking part of the data and them displaying it with some extra details like:

cout << "Name Of Student: " << ->Name of specific student data from the file<-;
cout << endl;

Unfortunately, thats the best I can describe my problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share with us your code to see how did you try to tackle the described problem.

Comment: I meant to edit your question and share with us the relevant part from the question perspective.  Do not upload your source code to some file sharing site.